# delete from MySQL table after matching constraints

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete everything from a table `nalocation`

My `sql` is:

```
DELETE FROM `nalocation` nl, nafeatureimp nf, nasequenceimp ns, bga_SRes.taxon t
WHERE nl.`na_feature_ID` = nf.`na_feature_ID`
AND nf.`na_sequence_ID` = ns.na_sequence_ID
AND ns.taxon_ID = t.taxon_ID
AND t.taxon_ID =755178
```

But I am getting an error `1064`.. I suppose this is because I'm wronly trying to delete everything from all the tables I'm joining.

How do I delete everything from `nalocation` after matching all these constraints?

Comment: I think you can just add `nl` between the words `DELETE` and `FROM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the alias of the table you want to delete from between the words `DELETE` and `FROM`

```
DELETE nl FROM `nalocation` nl, nafeatureimp nf, nasequenceimp ns, bga_SRes.taxon t
WHERE nl.`na_feature_ID` = nf.`na_feature_ID`
AND nf.`na_sequence_ID` = ns.na_sequence_ID
AND ns.taxon_ID = t.taxon_ID
AND t.taxon_ID =755178
```

Answer (score 1):

CAN YOU TRY THIS,

`DELETE n1, nf, ns, t FROM`nalocation`nl, nafeatureimp nf, nasequenceimp ns, bga_SRes.taxon t
WHERE nl.`na_feature_ID`= nf.`na_feature_ID
`AND nf.`na_sequence_ID`= ns.na_sequence_ID
AND ns.taxon_ID = t.taxon_ID
AND t.taxon_ID ='755178'`

**Note**

If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when referring to the table.

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html